# How can I return an array from a function?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to set up a function that will append values to an array. When I try to return the array from the function instead of getting the newly appended array I just get an empty one `[]`.

I know the rest of the code works when it is all inside one function however I have been tasked with specifically defining the values outside the function and only appending inside the function.

Is there a way to return the newly appended array in order to append to it again?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros(0) #setting up empty array

def append_to_array (arr, value):
    arr = np.append(arr, value) #appends value to array
    print(arr) #prints array with appended value
    return(arr)

inputs = True
while inputs:
    value = input("Enter the next number to be added to the array, 'Done' to stop the loop: ")
    if value == "Done":
        inputs = False
    else:
        append_to_array(arr, float(value))
print(value)
```

Comment: You _do_ return it. You just don't _do anything_ with the return value.

Comment: See it this way: your function is a sender, who sends a value, a list in yout case.  But who is the reciever? Who **recieves** this value? Where does this value arrive?

Comment: What am I supposed to change in order to then use the returned value. My understanding is that `arr` should be the appended array and when it loops through again it should use that as the `arr` variable sent to the function. If that is a fundamental misunderstanding I would appreciate you explaining how.

Comment: The `arr=` inside the function makes it a local variable, no longer connected to `arr` argument.  That's a python issue.

Comment: list append works in-place.  `np.append` returns a new array, thus isn't as efficient.  It shouldn't be used in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to assign the returned array back to the original `arr`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros(0) #setting up empty array

def append_to_array (arr, value):
    arr = np.append(arr, value) #appends value to array
    print(arr) #prints array with appended value
    return(arr)

inputs = True
while inputs:
    value = input("Enter the next number to be added to the array, 'Done' to stop the loop: ")
    if value == "Done":
        inputs = False
    else:
        arr = append_to_array(arr, float(value))
```

or use a pythons (non-numpy) arrays (a.k.a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)):

```
arr = [] #setting up empty array

def append_to_array (arr, value):
    arr.append(value) #appends value to array
    print(arr) #prints array with appended value

inputs = True
while inputs:
    value = input("Enter the next number to be added to the array, 'Done' to stop the loop: ")
    if value == "Done":
        inputs = False
    else:
        append_to_array(arr, float(value))
```

---

Sindenote: I suggest using [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
arr = [] #setting up empty array

def append_to_array (arr, value):
    arr.append(value) #appends value to array
    print(arr) #prints array with appended value

while True:
    value = input("Enter the next number to be added to the array, 'Done' to stop the loop: ")
    if value == "Done":
        break
    append_to_array(arr, float(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the return value of function `def append_to_array (arr, value)`.

Something like this will do, if you keep everything the same

```
...
    if value == "Done":
        inputs = False
    else:
        arr = append_to_array(arr, float(value))
...
```